# Rails app SSL is not being applied to the whole platform.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I am running my rails app on nginx server. I am trying make the platform HTTPS secure. I purchased SSL certificate and configured it on the EC2 instance and configured the **nginx.conf** file accordingly too. After everything was done I entered **domain.com** on browser. For first time it redirected to **https**. But that's about it. Only home page was **HTTPS** the rest of the application as I went on exploring was still on **HTTP**

I am attaching my nginx.conf file and config/environment/production.rb files :

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  #listen 80 default_server deferred;
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;

  server_name domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/5532202b90020bc.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;

  root /home/deploy/apps/vendaxoprod/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  #location ^~ /assets/ {
    #gzip_static on;
    #expires max;
    #add_header Cache-Control public;
  #}

  location ^~ /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
}
```

**config/environment/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js ^[^_]*.css *.css.erb )

  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  #config.serve_static_assets = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  #config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["SMTP_HOST"] }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = ENV["SMTP_HOST"]
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    #Enter the smtp provider here ex: smtp.mandrillapp.com
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    port: ENV['SMTP_PORT'].to_i,
    #Enter the smtp domain here ex: vendaxo.com
    domain: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"],
    #Enter the user name for smtp provider here
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USERNAME"],
    #Enter the password for smtp provider here
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: Make sure all of your links within the app are relative.

Comment: All are linked. Everything is dynamic. If you want me to add any particular file information for this I can add.  @TheWhizofOz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add separate server blocks for handle redirection to `https`.Like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com; 
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 default ssl;

  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate <certificate_path>;
  ssl_certificate_key <certificate_key>;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your virtual file in Nginx as follows,

Add a separate section for requests that come in port 80 and redirect all such requests to port 443 (or HTTPS)

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    my.domain.com;

    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Then, in your current configuration remove **listen 80**

```
server {
    listen         443 ssl;
    server_name    my.domain.com;
    # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Tried your solution. I added another server block as you said in the first segment and I removed `listen 80` in my existing block. But didn't work. I also tried setting          `config.force_ssl = true` as suggested by someone outside stackflow and that caused server to go down saying `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`